# How to hide div class text for mobile devices or mobile view only?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to hide text content on splash screen of website. How to hide it with css or html code?

This is for perl based script with html and css based splash screen on homepage. This is the [website](https://rarlink.com). You can see the texts are messed on mobile devices.

I've tried below code to hide text on mobile:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #content {
       display: none;
    }
}
```

into this code:

```
</br>


    <div id="content">
    <div class="container" style="position: relative;top: 50%; transform: translateY(15%)">
        <div class="prompic" style="">
            <a href="<TMPL_VAR site_url>/?op=upload_form">&nbsp;</a>
        </div>  
            <div class="splashbar promsign">
            <a href="<TMPL_VAR site_url>/register.html">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="pheader">
                        <span><img src="<TMPL_VAR site_url>/images/icon_sup_blue.png"></span>
                        <span>SignUp</span>
                    <div class="clear">
                Whenever you need to send a file that is too large for e-mail, <b><TMPL_VAR site_name></b> can help. If you need secure remote storage capacity for off-site backups, <b><TMPL_VAR site_name></b> offers best solutions for you.
                </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="splashbar promprofit">
            <a href="<TMPL_VAR site_url>/make_money.html">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="pheader">
                        <span><img src="<TMPL_VAR site_url>/images/icon_profit_blue.png"></span>
                        <span>Become Affiliate</span>
                    <div class="clear">
                    With <b><TMPL_VAR site_name></b> you can earn money by promoting your files on the external resources. Just register and enjoy being a part of one or more of our affiliate programs!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            </a>
        </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>       
    </div>
        <div class="col-12 lft splashHldr">
        <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net." target="_new"><img src="/images/android.png" height="61"></a>
        <a href="/desktop_file_manager_mac.zip" target="_new"><img src="/images/mac_os.png" height="61"></a>
        <a href="/desktop_file_manager_win.zip" target="_new"><img src="/images/windows.png" height="61"></a>
    </div>
    </br>
        <div id="content" style="width: 980px">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="clear">
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <b><TMPL_VAR site_name></b> is a cloud-based file hosting provider. We offer online cloud storage/remote backup capacity, sophisticated uploading and downloading tools. 
                        </div>
                </a>

    <style>
    body{background-image:url(../images/bg.png); -webkit-background-size:cover; -moz-background-size:cover; -o-background-size:cover; background-size:cover;}
    #header{background:none!important; border:0px!important;}
    footer{background:none; border:0px;position:absolute;bottom:0px;}
    footer .container1{display:none;}
    #mainmenu ul li a{color:#fff;}
    .copyright{display:block;}
    .prompic{margin: 50px auto 30px;}

    @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    #container{margin:0px auto;}
    .prompic{margin: 10px auto 10px;}
    }
    @media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 800px) {
    #container{margin:0px auto;}
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #content {
       display: none;
    }
}
    </style>
```

I expect to hide these messy texts on mobile devices but it didn't take any effect.
How to do it properly?

Comment: display: none !important; might be your help

Comment: no didnt work too

Answer (score 1):

`min-width: 800px` selects screens with a width of 800px **or higher**. Try `max-width` instead:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
...
```

Comment: tried but it still doesn't take any effect nothing changed

Comment: Looking through your HTML/CSS there are some additional problems. You have two div's that are tagged with an ID of "content", which is not correct HTML/CSS syntax, and there isn't actually the @media selector you mentioned inside your style.css file.

Comment: so what can i do?

Comment: An ID tag can only be used once on an HTML file. You can try changing both divs to `class="content"` instead and edit your CSS accordingly. However, I can't help you figure out why your style.css file is not actually the version you want since you're the one in charge of deploying code to your server.

Answer (score 0):

```
`https://codepen.io/kunalvijan/pen/oRmRwp`
```

i have created a dummy codepen for you. just check and see if the solution works for you

Comment: i have updated the pen its working fine. check again

Comment: nope still didnt take any effect, note: i am adding css code into the same splash.html file under the above code..